# Thumb function pointers with position independent code?

Tags: arm, ld, thumb

I want function `caller` to take a thumb function pointer as an argument:

```
void fun(void) {}

void caller(void(*f)(void)) {
    f();
}

void _start(void) {
    caller(fun);
}
```

When I compile it with

```
arm-elf-gcc -mthumb -c -fpic test.c
```

and then link

```
arm-elf-ld test.o
```

, linker tries to wrap `fun` with interwork code and warns about interworking not enabled. But I don't want to enable interwork, because I want it to be thumb-only code. Without `-fpic`, code compiles and function pointer works correctly.

If want to ask why I have to pass thumb function pointers and provide PIC code, it's because the API which I can't change.

Edit:
Gcc version is 4.7.2. Specifying `-march=armv4t -mcpu=arm7tdmi` didn't help.

Comment: Which version of gcc? Did you try with a newer gcc?

Comment: It is very important to specify the CPU or `-march` parameter with *thumb* code.  Older versions did not support *thumb* as well.  At least *armv5* with `blx rX`, etc. are available and *inter-networking* is not required.  See: [Gcc ARM options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html), especially, `-mno-thumb-interwork`.

Comment: You really have an `-march=armv4t` CPU?  That is extremely old!  If you are really mixing ARM and Thumb and using function pointers with an arm7tdmi, then there is no choice.  If only *thumb*, then use `-mno-thumb-interwork` and `-mthumb`.

Comment: @artlessnoise That's right, it's old, it's in a mobile phone from 2001. `-mno-thumb-interwork` is default option and specifying it leads to exactly same behavior.

Comment: Possibly this is a linker issue.  PIC code is typical for shared libraries and you want these to work with ARM/Thumb in the caller so the normal case is to have interworking with PIC.